# Access dynamically changed js variable in code behind (C#)

Tags: c#, javascript

I want to access variable sec and min in code behind C# for some validation
.As sec and min is dynamically changing is it good to use hidden field to store it and then access it in C#?

`var sec=15;
    var min=100;

```
var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function timer()
{
  sec=sec-1;

  if(sec < 0)
  {
    sec=59;
    min--;
  }
  else
  {
    min=min;
  }
  if(sec <=9 ){
    sec = "0"+sec;
  }

  document.getElementById("lblCountDown").innerHTML= "Time Left: "+(min<=9 ? "0" + min : min)+" mins"+" "+sec + " secs";`
```

Comment: No. This is worse idea. You save last request time in server. Then use like this `var timespan=DateTime.Now-SavedTime; ` then check `timespan.TotalSeconds`

Comment: Maybe you can save to in Session. `Session["lastTime"]=DateTime.Now` etc

Comment: i want to save values of min and sec variables when form is submited. So can u suggest any other way

Comment: The solution could actually depend on your scenario. Would you explain what you are trying to do? Are you just trying to save the date/time of the form submission?

Comment: when min=0 and sec=0 my form is autosubmitted bt if min>0 and user clicks on submit button then only an alert box saying "are you sure you want to submit?" should pop up and not when form is autosubmitted

Answer (score 0):

If you want, use this. On the server side get `Request.Form["min"]`

```
<input type="hidden" id="min" name="min"/>
<input type="hidden" id="sec" name="sec"/>
```

on the Javascript:

```
...
document.getElementById("lblCountDown").innerHTML= "Time Left: "+(min<=9 ? "0" + min : min)+" mins"+" "+sec + " secs";`

document.getElementById("min").value=min;
document.getElementById("sec").value=sec;
```

**Remember** this is worse idea